# How to trace code in ASP.Net MVC from frontend to backend?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been given a large MVC solution to fix bugs in. I'm skilled in C#, but I have no experience with ASP, and I don't seem to be able find good debugging/tracing tutorials on MVC.

How can I understand which view/views is the startup page of the app?

How can I trace which C# method is called when a button in my chrome browser (local debugging via IIS in VS for web 2013) is pressed for example?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_controllers.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check your route config for the default page and routes;

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source code I can recommend [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) for server side logging in real time.
Furthermore if you are not familiar with MVC conventions I would recommend a short tutorial like this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_app.asp). There is a lot more stuff online.